# CSS styling not taking effect

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="contact-details">
    <p id="contact-details-first">
        <h3>Address:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>238 Parsley</li>
            <li>Annlin, Pretoria</li>
            <li>South Africa</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
#contact-details {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: auto;
}

#contact-details-first > h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#contact-details-first > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

For some reason the bottom two css style don't take effect.

```
#contact-details-first > h3
#contact-details-first > ul
```

Comment: The html must reference the css file if it's outside. Please add all relevant parts of the HTML file, especially the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest block elements inside paragraphs.

It works if you change the `p` with `div`, like this:

```css
#contact-details {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: auto;
}

#contact-details-first > h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#contact-details-first > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-details">
<div id="contact-details-first">
 <h3>Address:</h3>
 <ul>
  <li>238 Parsley</li>
  <li>Annlin, Pretoria</li>
  <li>South Africa</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it! And now i know a little more :)

Answer (score 0):

`ul` and `heading` not allowed inside of `paragraph`, change `p` tag in to div.

```css
#contact-details {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: auto;
}

#contact-details-first  h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#contact-details-first  ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-details">
  <div id="contact-details-first">
    <h3>Address:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>238 Parsley</li>
      <li>Annlin, Pretoria</li>
      <li>South Africa</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```